# How to concatenate path and varying file names - C++

Tags: c++, concatenation

This is my code:

```
double loglikelihood = 0; 
double loglikelihood1 = 0;
double THRESHOLD = 5;
double c = THRESHOLD + 1; 

std::ofstream llh_file;
std::ofstream myfile;   
const char *path= "path_of_file_to_be_saved";
myfile = ( string(path) + flags.inference_result_file_.c_str() ); 

for (int iter = 0; c > THRESHOLD; ++iter) {     
    std::cout << "Iteration " << iter << " ...\n";  
    loglikelihood = 0; 

    llh_file.open(myfile.c_str() );
    loglikelihood += sampler.LogLikelihood(&document);
    llh_file << "THE LOGLIKELIHOOD FOR ITER " << iter << " " << "IS: " << loglikelihood << "\n";                  
    llh_file.close();
```

I am a newbie to C++. I have a folder containing different file names. I want to do some process in the for loop and save the results in the folder with the exact file names as the input files. How do I do it? Please help!

Comment: Read more about [Programming using C++](http://stroustrup.com/programming.html); use C++11 at least; learn about `std::string`, see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp)

Comment: Once you've done that, check out [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm).

Comment: Folders are OS specific; POSIX and Linux have directories, not folders. You could have a C++ implementation without any kind of folder (and even without directories). On POSIX, consider [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) etc... & [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html)

Comment: See [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/308481/40065). Maybe I am nitpicking, but if you googled on "read directory" you'll immediately find what I mention. Your question should mention what operating system you are interested in. Or consider [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) or [Qt](http://qt.io/). BTW C++11 does not know about folders or directories.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To concatenate strings. Use std::string instead of char*.
like:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
int main() {
    std::string path = "path";
    std::string file = "file.txt";
    std::string myfile = path + "/" + "file.txt";
    std::string fname = "test.txt";
    std::ofstream f(fname);
    f << myfile;
}
```

this will write "path/file.txt" in the file named test.txt.

Comment: this is exactly what I want. But, I want to save it in a file. This is printing the output. How to save it in a file as the input file name? The input file is in flags.inference_result_file_.c_str(). I am trying to save it in a file.

Comment: edited to write a string in a file. But you will have to adapt it to your code. I won't do all your job :)

Comment: hehe.. I figured it out ;) Thanks for the help :)